# create <image> in <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an `<img>` in a `<td>`

```
$myRow = $("<tr></tr>");
$myRow.append("<td>$('<img/>').attr({ src: 'xx' })</td>"),
```

as expected it's considering it as a string.
How to format this using jQuery, so that it creates an `<img>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$myRow = $("<tr></tr>");
$('<td></td>').appendTo($myRow)
    .append($('<img/>')
        .attr({ src: 'xx' })
    ),
    // ...
);
```